# How to access c:set variable from jsp to javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I tried declaring the variable in my JSP:

```
<script> var _csrf.token = "${_csrf.token}"; </script>
```

And then accessed it in my ts file in this code, below, it displayed the value correctly.

```
console.log(window['_csrf.token']);
```

However, I am getting an **undefined** on this scenario, my purpose is to hide it in the browser for security purpose.

I have this code on **JSP**

```
<c:set var="_csrf.token" value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

And tried to access on Angular **.ts** file using this code.

```
console.log(window['_csrf.token']);
```

Am I correct with using the jstl tag or not? I don't really know how. Can someone teach me how to get the value from the jsp to ts file?

Comment: @BalusC by the way, concern with putting it in <script> tag is it can be seen when you hit f12 from the browser, someone told me that use jstl c:set however i didnt know how to access in in my ts. I used window[''_csrf.token''] but it returned undefined.

Comment: It returns undefined because it isn't defined as a JS variable. You have nowhere written `window['_csrf.token'] = "${_csrf.token}";` in JavaScript.

Comment: @BalusC i updated the question. kindly read it if do we have the same scenario because i dont know how. thanks

Comment: `window['_csrf.token']` is not the same as `var _csrf.token`. This is basic JavaScript.